# Inject HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest on ContainerResponseFilter using dropwizard

Tags: java, filter, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I have been developing a project with dropwizard-guicey, Rignt now I'm setting up a security project and they have something like this:

```
@Provider
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter{

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {
        this.httpServletRequest.getAttributeNames();
}



}
```

They are getting a null pointer exception, is there any way I could make this work?

Comment: How are you registering it?

Comment: If you're registering it as instance, try registering it as a class.

Comment: I believe we answered that in your bug report. Guice has no idea about context, this is a different eco system. At creation time of the Filter singleton, there is no request to be injected. You need to inject a provider for the request, so that guice can resolve this variable at request time.